# Container<ImplementerOfIInterface> is not Container<IInterface>. Why not?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Why wouldn't `DoesntWork()` work below?  The error is:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'List' to 'IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`.  I know this is something about generic/templates I'm not getting, but List is IEnumerable and Implementer *is an* IInterface.  I don't see why this needs to be casted (or if it really can be).

```
public interface IInterface
{
    // ...
}

public class Implementer : IInterface
{
    // ...
}

IEnumerable<IInterface> DoesntWork()
{
    List<Implementer> result = new List<Implementer>();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ee207183%28v=vs.140%29). Here's a nice blog [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/covariance-and-contravariance-faq). If you are not using 4.0 you will have to cast the list using the System.Linq [Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-5.0) method.

Answer (score 2):

This works with Net 4.0:
public interface IEnumerable<**out** T> : IEnumerable
*out* is contravariant